# Why can't I craft a badge when I have 5 different cards?

Tags: steam, steam-trading-cards

I have 5 different cards for The Binding Of Isaac, but I can't find anywhere to craft a badge.
Do I need the exact 5 cards shown in the badges page within steam (as below)?

[image]

I thought those were just a random 5.

---

Note: I have since sold the cards which is why the above image shows me having none.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You need at least 1 of each card there is for a game (in a given series, assuming there will be more than 1 series per game in the future) to craft a badge.

Answer (score 18):

Examining your profile more carefully:
[image]

The cards that are faded out are cards you must also get in order to fully craft a badge.  Keep in mind, the amount of drops you can get are roughly half of the amount needed to craft the badge.

You'll have to either trade to get your other cards,  or buy one via the Steam Market.

Answer (score 6):

To craft a badge, you need one of each card in the series. You get a predetermined number of card drops at first, and then once those are gone, you're eligible for "booster packs" that are randomly assigned. You can also trade cards from other games, or get them from friends. However you do it, you must have every card the game has in order to craft the badge

Comment: For now at least, you get half of the number of cards in a set (rounded up) by playing. (If there are 7 cards you find 4.) And you can get duplicates.

Comment: I believe booster packs only drop if you have the level 1 version of the badge.

Comment: @Batophobia nope.

Comment: No, they can get dropped no matter what, according to the steam rules.

Comment: @zorpix I think you can only get boosters when you have completed all the card drops that you can get from a game. Unless they changed that rule recently.

Comment: well yes, but I meant no matter what once you're eligible. Sorry I didnt specify!

Answer (score 5):

Specifically for The Binding of Isaac, there are 9 cards you must collect. Once you have all nine, on that exact page there will be a button that says "Craft badge".

Some games have as few as 5 cards to collect (such as The Walking Dead), others have upwards of 15 (such as Brutal Legend).

Comment: There are games that have fewer than 8. One of the lowest I think is 5, with The Walking Dead being one of these games if I remember correctly.

Comment: Thanks, I've modified my answer to accommodate the more accurate info.